# How to reduce number of parameters in go nested function calls

Tags: go

I have a go Calltree which is structured as follows:

```
// state is a common struct shared among all "instances" of MyType - simulating member variables for an Interface
(s MyType) Run(state *State){ // called from outside
  // define goroutines that fetch something via http
  HTTPCallback(){ // runs on every http response
    parseData(record, outputChan)
  }
}
(s MyType) parseData(rec []string, outputChan chan(interface{})){
  // doesn't need anything from "state" so far
  doIdMapping(string) 
}


doIdMapping(key) { 
   return state.Map[key] 
}
```

Is there a way of getting access to the Map (which is completely constant) **without** being forced to pass the "state" through HTTPCallback and all the goroutines above which end up in calling HTTPCallback?

This is not only bad for a clear code but also is bad when it comes to testing. All the intermediate functions carry around that struct pointer which they don't even need to depend on. Did I miss something about the language design of go? :/

Comment: If it's a "common struct shared among all 'instances' of MyType" and "completely constant", sounds like it could maybe safely be a global, potentially private to the package where these functions are defined. If there's a reason it can't be, it might be helpful to revise those comments to help clear up the question.

Comment: Your example is, at minimum, missing all the `func` keywords. Ideally sample/example code should compile but (IMO) at minimum it should be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of this is within a single package you can simply declare `State` at the package level and use it everywhere. For example;

```
package myHttpClient

import (
    "allthatstuff"
)

state State // not exported but available everywhere in 'myHttpClient'
ExternState State // exported so anyone importing myHttpClient can do myHttpClient.ExternState
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'll try that and tell you about my progress & upvote accordingly :)